# MVC C# - DataTable in DataRows with Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datatable

I have the following `DataTable` records :-

I want to display the `Rows` for which `HeaderPrintOrder` Column don't have `0` as value. And in PDF Cell I have to print `FieldName` : `Amount` by iterating to the records with above given condition.

I am trying the below code, gives me error `Cannot interpret token '!'`. What is correct way to do this?

[image]

```
var datatable = new DataTable();
datatable.Load(reader);

DataRow[] HeadingFields = datatable.Select("HeaderPrintOrder != 0");
                    foreach (var item in HeadingFields)
                    {
                        cellHead = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(HeadingFields[item]["FieldName"].ToString() + " : " + HeadingFields[item]["Amount"].ToString(), fntTableFont));
                        cellHead.Colspan = 3;
                        MainTable.AddCell(cellHead);
                    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With LINQ it's easy:

```
var filtered = datatable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<int>("HeaderPrintOrder") != 0);
foreach(DataRow row in filtered)
{
    //  ....
}
```

With `DataTable.Select` you have to use `<>` instead of `!=`:

```
DataRow[] HeadingFields = datatable.Select("HeaderPrintOrder <> 0");
```

`<>` is supported whereas `!=` is not. You can see that here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: In `foreach` How do i get `FieldName` & `Amount`?

Comment: @Anup: you can use the same way that you've used since it's just a `DataRow`. However, i would use `Field` which is a `DataRow` extension method. It is strong typed and supports nullables.

Answer (score 0):

Try with Linq:

```
var HeadingFields= from row in datatable .AsEnumerable()
                   where row.Field<int>("HeaderPrintOrder") <> (int)(0)
                   select row;
```

Answer (score 0):

The != operator is not supported by the RowFilter syntax.

Try:

```
DataRow[] HeadingFields = datatable.Select("NOT (HeaderPrintOrder = 0)");
```